# Open some specific Facebook account using Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

I have my android app and I would like next:

- When somebody press the button on my application it will load the Facebook application with my facebook page.

Is there a chance to open a my facebook page in the official Facebook app from my app code?
I do not want to give access to my page to all who have the application but only download them my facebook page like for visitors

Comment: Have you looked into using the Facebook API?

Comment: Yes, I have looked and I didn't find anything =(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I personally would use Intent to start up the FB app by typing the package name. like com.facebook.home or whatever activities FB app got

//Simon

Comment: I can to load facebook app from my. But I dont know how to load my Facebook page for users which login using their own acount.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to set the mime type of the `Intent` to `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.profile` (using `intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.facebook.profile");`